# xCode 4.3.2 - build for profiling, how do you run the app?

Tags: ios, xcode

In xCode I click "Product -> build for -> profiling".

Then I hold down the run button until the drop down menu appears and select profiling. xCode runs and says "Finished running - Profiling MyApp.app on iDeviceName". However, the app never runs...

How do I build for profiling and then run?

Answer (score 2):

Use,

Product -> Profile

from the Xcode menu.  This will start up Instruments, and you can run the app from there.

Comment: Just tried that. xCode ran and gave me "Finished running - Profiling MyApp.app on iDeviceName" without ever running the app. Note, the app is not currently installed on my device. The only way to install it is to product -> run? (which does not use profiling build)

Answer (score 1):

Run the app on your device. Open instruments and then pick your target. Xcode 4.3.2 has serious issues with the profiling. This is the only workaround I've found
[image]

Comment: How do i get a release build on my app to profile before it is on the app store?

Comment: You can just plug in your device to your computer. Select your device  on the drop down list next to the STOP button. And just build directly onto the device. You don't need to send the app to the app store to test it on a live device. I would STRONGLY recommend you at least see the Getting started videos on the Developer Member centre (http://developer.apple.com) this is an elemental skill you should be familiar with

Comment: I understand that, and I do it all the time. My question is, "is there a way to get a non-debug build" ie. release build onto my iPhone for testing before sending to the app store. When you build as you mentioned it is a debug build on your iPhone.

Comment: Right where it should show you your project name. Just select edit scheme. click on the Run &{PRODUCT NAME HERE} and change the Build Configuration to Release.